# Pdfpages - titlesec seems to be ignored with option pagecommand

Tags: chapters, titles, titlesec, appendices, pdfpages

When using pdfpages, I got a problem with titlesec formatting with frame style.

Excepted:
[image]
Actual:
[image]

Any ideas ? Here is my MWE (you can include whatever dummy pdf) :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

% renamming stuff
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Annexe}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Annexes}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Annexes}
\renewcommand{\setthesection}{\Alph{section}}

% Title style
\makeatletter
  \titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
    {\normalfont}
    { \filright 
      \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ 
      \thechapter 
      \enspace
    }
    {0.5em}
    {\Large\filleft\textsc}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{25pt}{25pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{TEST}
    \pagebreak
    \includepdf[
        pages=-,
        offset=0cm -1cm,
        width=\textwidth,
        pagecommand={
            \chapter{Breaking example}
        },
    ]{example-image-duck.pdf}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

includepdf sets \fboxrule to zero, and so the rules are no longer seen. You can reset this in the page command:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

% renamming stuff
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Annexe}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Annexes}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Annexes}
\renewcommand{\setthesection}{\Alph{section}}

% Title style
\makeatletter
  \titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
    {\normalfont}
    { \filright
      \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\
      \thechapter
      \enspace
    }
    {0.5em}
    {\Large\filleft\textsc}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{25pt}{25pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{TEST}
    \pagebreak
    \includepdf[
        pages=1-10,
        offset=0cm -1cm,
        width=\textwidth,
        pagecommand={
            \fboxrule0.4pt
            \chapter{Breaking example}
        },
    ]{example-image-duck.pdf}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Never have guessed that in their documentations ... Thanks